# C3js - How to change the width of a bottom-left legend

Tags: c3.js

I would like to change the size of my legend because after using a position inset with bottom-left my legends elements doesn't have the same space between element:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/9460795/58431609-d9e77400-80ae-11e9-97c6-9efbd89bd558.png

I already tried to change the bar width but nothing happen

```
legend: { position: 'inset', padding: 10, inset: { anchor: 'bottom-left', x: -5, y: -50 - (20 * (this.selectedData.length - 2)), step: 1 }, item: { onmouseover: (id) => this.mouseOverLegendItem(id), onmouseout: (id) => this.mouseOutLegendItem(id), onclick: (id) => this.onmouseClickLegendItem(id) } }, bar: { width: 30 },
```

How can i fix it please ?
I'm newbi on c3 sorry :(

C3 version:"^0.6.13",
D3 version: "^5.9.1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this fixed width seems to be baked into the positioning code when the legend is of type 'inset'. If you want the legend to display horizontally with no extra spacing between the items you're going to have to set the legend position as 'bottom'.

There is if you do that a hack whereby you can move that bottom legend into the chart area to mimic an inset though, but it's fairly brittle - see https://jsfiddle.net/5odf8w0x/

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1ytuytuytutyuu', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25],
            ['data3', 10, 20, 30, 40, 60, 70]
        ]
    },
    legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
    },
    onrendered: function () {
        console.log(this, this.config);
        var x = +d3.select(this.config.bindto).select(".c3-legend-item text").attr("x");
        x -= 70; // for axis and margin
        d3.select(this.config.bindto).selectAll(".c3-legend-item").attr("transform", "translate(-"+x+",-50)");
    }
});
```